# how to run a script in every 10 minutes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to run a shell script in every 10 minutes.
I am appending the output in a log file every time script runs.
I need to stop the script from running once the size of the log file reached to 10 MB.
how can this be achieved , please help !!

```
./test.sh >> log_file
```

Comment: Use `cron` or `anacron`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
maximumsize=10000 #KB

while :
do
    ./test.sh >> log_file
    actualsize=$(du -k log_file | cut -f 1)
    if [ $actualsize -gt $maximumsize ];then
        echo "logsize exceed.stop."
        break
    fi

    sleep 600
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your test script : put your process into a function, add your function into a loop, condition of the loop (size of your log file under 10MB) and at the end of the loop add a `sleep 600` to wait for ten minutes

Answer (score 0):

You might add to the start of your test.sh script a test, if the log file > 10MB then do not run (exit), or you could archive (maybe `gzip -9` or `xz -9`) the log, if it's all text output then it should compress a LOT. Or you could pipe the script's output through gzip to compress it right away.

And also use cron/anacron to run the script regularly, like add `*/10 * * * * user test.sh` to /etc/crontab...